# Windows 10 Reset PC cannot erase TPM

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, reset

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 - i7559 laptop with windows 10. I am trying to reset the PC completely, with all the settings, hard drive completely refreshed.

I am doing it from the BIOS's troubleshooting [page](https://images.app.goo.gl/FPKiezSEAJNYCuDY7). Because I cannot access my PC anymore. It is blocked at the profile password input page here below [image]

If I click on "set up my PIN", it brings back to this page, so I couldn't not set a new PIN.

When I reset it from BIOS, the resetting process stops at this step: [image]

When I press F12, it undoes the resetting and goes back to the "set up my PIN" page. If I press ESC, the same thing happens.

I wasn't able to find a similar situation as mine from my research. Most people had the issue of after pressing F12, nothing happened. I am positive that my F12 key works properly, because I connected an old USB keyboard, and by pressing the F12 with a keyboard, the same issue happened.

I just want to reset this PC to factory setting, erasing TPM does not matter to me. How should I reset it?

Comment: Who set the BIOS password?   Does that person (organization) know the password?

Comment: Just boot from a standard windows 10 USB stick and perform a clean install. You can create the installation media using Microsoft's media creation tool found at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @John I did, it doesn't let me enter my password. Every time I click on "set my PIN", it just goes back to the previous page.

Comment: @Silbee The thing is that I can't get pass the "enter the password" page.

Comment: You will have to build the installation media on another PC yes. However, once you boot from that on your currently 'broken' PC, reinstalling windows will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I reset my PC a few times, the same error persisted. Whenever I chose to erase TPM or not, it cancels the resetting. But after several times, maybe 9-10 times, pressing F12 to erase TPM finally worked, and my PC is reset properly. Still don't understand what the problem was.

Comment: I guess the 9th or 10th time's the charm!

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell Resetting TPM

You can give some of the PowerShell TPM commands a shot by running them from an elevated (run as administrator) PowerShell command prompt to reset the TPM settings.

**Clearing**

See [Clear-Tpm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603122(v=wps.630).aspx) and [Set-TpmOwnerAuth](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603120.aspx) for further detail but below are a few to give a shot:

- `Clear-Tpm`
- `Initialize-Tpm -AllowClear -AllowPhysicalPresence`

**Default Value**

You may also want to consider looking over [Initialize-Tpm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603112(v=wps.630).aspx) and note that *if you do not specify an owner authorization value, the cmdlet attempts to read the value from the registry* so this may be reading and setting by default what you don't know from this value.

**New Value**

You may want to consider running [ConvertTo-TpmOwnerAuth](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603113(v=wps.630).aspx) command to explicitly specify the new owner passphrase. So incorporate this into your process accordingly:

- `ConvertTo-TpmOwnerAuth -PassPhrase "<newpasswordstring>"`

---

Also see [How to Clear the TPM Chip of any previous Ownership Credentials](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN155219/en) and be sure to follow those instructions step-by-step if you've not already done so.

> ### [How to Clear the TPM Chip of any previous Ownership Credentials](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN155219/en)
>
> > <sub>*This article provides information on how to reset the TPM chip and clear all previous owner details*.</sub>

> **You are unable to reset DDPA or DCP credentials on your system**
>
> You may encounter an issue whilst attempting to reset the **DDP|A** or
> **DCP** credentials, where you are prompted for a Trusted Platform Module (TPM) ownership password.
>
> If you have lost the **TPM password, the TPM chip can be cleared using
> Windows**.
>
> > <sub>*Notice: This will completely erase the TPM credential store, including hard drive encryption, fingerprints, smart cards, etc.
> > Please check which security devices you are using that may be
> > affected. Make sure you have a Windows password set up and set for
> > login.*</sub>
>
> ### How to reset and clear the TPM Chip
>
> The first thing to do is to remove any **pre-boot passwords** in the
> **DDP|A** console.
>
> **This will not affect the Windows password.**
>
> You must be **able to validate** just as in any credential scenario,
> and you must be **an administrator on this system** in order to
> perform this function.
>
> 1. Click **Start**. In the **Search\Run** box, type **tpm.msc** and press **ENTER**.
> 2. Under the **Actions section** on the right, click **Clear TPM**.
> 3. In the **Clear the TPM Security Hardware** box, check **I don't have the TPM owner password** and click **OK**.
> 4. You will be asked to Reboot. Just after the Dell **POST** screen, you will be prompted to press a key (usually **F10**) to clear **TPM.
>    Press that key**.
> 5. Once the system reboots, you will be prompted to restart and follow the instructions to **enable TPM**. Restart.
> 6. Just after the Dell **POST** screen, you will be prompted to press a key to enable TPM. Press that key (**usually F10**).
>
> > *<sub>Note: If you do not use TPM, press the **ESC** key.</sub>*
>
> 7. Once back at the desktop, either the **TPM Setup Wizard** appears for you to enter a **TPM owner password** or you can choose **Change
>    Owner Password**.
>
> You can now clear **DDP|A credentials** through the **DDP|A console**.
>
> For more information, please check out the article below :
>
> - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753694.aspx
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN155219/en)</sub>

Comment: I was trying on the diagnostics command window, none of the two clearing commands work. It says they are not external nor internal commands.

Comment: I `cd`ed into the windowspowershell location, still `Clear-Tpm` and `Initialize-Tpm` are not recognized as internal nor external commands.